# R - Create list of numbers

Tags: r, list, recursion, data-structures

I have a named vector defining some colors.

```
my_colors = c("C_T" = "salmon", "C_G" = "gold", "C_A" = "mediumseagreen", "T_G" = "lightseagreen", "T_C" = "royalblue1", "T_A" = "orchid1")
```

I want to create a list of size N in which each entry is named numerically and contains the vector my_colors. The structure of the list needs to fit a particular format because I am feeding it to some very rigid functions. Here's some code that produces the desired result manually and showcases the necessary structure:

```
my_list = list("1" = my_colors, "2" = my_colors, "3" = my_colors, "4" = my_colors, "5" = my_colors, "6" = my_colors)
str(my_list)
```

I have tried writing a loop to populate an empty list

```
test_list = list()
for (i in 1:6) {
  test_list[i] = my_colors
}
```

But this returns error messages complaining about the length

I have also tried

```
test_list = list()
for (i in 1:6) {
  test_list[[i]] = my_colors
}
```

and

```
test_list = list()
for (i in 1:6) {
  x = character(i) 
  test_list[x] = my_colors
}
```

but neither of these approaches gives me a test_list with the same structure as my_list has. How can I recreate the manual list-generation I used to populate my_list in a recursive fashion?

Comment: `rep(list(my_colors), N)`?

Comment: Try `my_list <- 'names<-'(rep(list(my_colors), n), 1:n)`

Comment: The approach with `test_list[[i]] = my_colors` in a loop seems to work fine..?

Comment: Or `replicate(6,my_colors, simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: Your second test_list works fine for me and produces the same structure as your hard coded one.

Comment: I think maybe the OP wants to `setNames` on the result... not clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you started with this (one of your efforts that should not have thrown any errors)

```
test_list = list()
for (i in 1:6) {
  test_list[[i]] = my_colors
}
```

... the only thing that is missing are the correct names. Easily fixed:

```
names(test_list) <- 1:6
```

Oh. And now I see that @PierreLafortune already suggested that. If before you added the `.Names` attribute, you had run `all.equal` on those two objects you would have seen this (possibly helpful) result:

```
> all.equal(my_list, test_list)
[1] "names for target but not for current"
```

You could also have looked at the underlying structure by typing

```
 dput(my_list)
 dput(test_list)
```

.... and noticing that there were differences in the "outer" attributes.